# AngularJS + Ionic 5 Tabs navigation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

For my native APP Project, I got two tabs, one is homepage tab, another tab called 'MyAccount' was shared by login page and account page.
After login successfully, it can navigate to the account page but when I click on the 'MyAccount' tab, it will navigate back to the login page. I need to manually refresh the page after login, then will not happen this issue.

Is there any solution on this without manually refresh the page? Thank You.

Below is the code of the **login.page.ts** :

```
verifyLogin(pgcode:string, password:string)
    {
      //call API to verify the login details
      this.http.get(url, headers)
      .subscribe((apiReturn : any) =>
      {
        if(apiReturn.error){
          //if login failed
          this.sendNotification(apiReturn.error);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/login', { replaceUrl: true }); //redirect to login page
        }else{
          //if login success
          this.sendNotification(apiReturn.message);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/myaccount', { replaceUrl: true });
        }
      },
      (error : any) =>
      {
        //unable to call the API
        this.sendNotification('Something went wrong!');
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/login', { replaceUrl: true }); //redirect to login page
      });
    }
```

Below is the code of the **tab.page.ts** :

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.loadCookie();
  }
  
  async loadCookie(){
    const cookie = await Storage.get({key: 'cookie'}); //get cookie's value from localStorage(same like session)
    //const cookie = '';
    if(cookie.value == null){
      this.cookieValue = null;
      this.myAccTab = '/tabs/login';
      console.log('FALSE:',null);
    }else{
      this.cookieValue = cookie.value;  //assign {{cookieValue}} in html then will echo the cookie value in homepage
      this.myAccTab = '/tabs/myaccount';
      console.log('TRUE:',cookie.value);
    }
  }
```

Below is the code of **tabs.page.html** :

```
      <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
          <ion-tab-button tab="home" [routerLink]="['/tabs/home']">
            <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button>
          <ion-tab-button [routerLink]="myAccTab">
            <ion-icon name="accessibility-outline"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>My Account</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button>
      </ion-tab-bar>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `this.loadCookie();` on the tab page after login successful.
You can publish an event after login and subscribe it in the tab page. In the event subscription you can call the `this.loadCookie()` function.